# Is jquery or animated png/gif better for image animation on a webpage?

Tags: jquery-animate, performance, animated-gif

Would it be better to use an animated gif/png or jquery for very fast image animation? Flash is not an option because of lack of iPhone/iPad support.

I have to add a row of flickering candles to a homepage (I know its a bad idea, but they wanted a 5-second animated splash screen so its a compromise). The image is approx 600 x 200px, and needs to be quick for the flame "flicker".

I have only used jquery for fading images so I don't know if it is suitable for this?

Any advise welcome, thanks!

Comment: Flash is still no longer an option because of everything support. (it's going away soon - happy new year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If speed is the issue, go with an animated gif. Use jQuery to swap out the animation with a static image after 5 seconds (preload the image while the gif animation is running so there is no delay during the swapping).

Comment: Thanks Ben. I'd +1 your answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, you can still mark it as the accepted answer if you want (that has no reputation requirement). Besides giving me 15 reputation, it increases your accepted answer % -- this will make people more likely to answer your questions in the future.